# Problema con comparador de arrays

Tags: java, array

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para clase en el que tengo que comparar dos arrays a través de un método (Sin utilizar Arrays.equals) , me saltan dos excepciones en la linea 9 y 26 que no comprendo.

```java
public class Comparador {

    public static boolean comparador(int x[], int y[]) {
        boolean z = false;
        if (x.length != y.length) {
            z = false;
        } else {
            for (int n = 0; n <= x.length; n++) {
                if (x[n] == y[n]) {
                    z = true;
                } else {
                    z = false;
                    break;

                }

            }
        }
        return z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] num2 = { 1, 2, 3 };

        boolean resul = comparador(num, num2);
        System.out.println(resul);

    }
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
        at Comparador.comparador(Comparador.java:9)
        at Comparador.main(Comparador.java:26)
```

Comment: Mi cerebro (ni el de nadie hasta donde yo llego) no compila java. Ni es capaz de adivinar qué errores te saltan. Por favor, añade los detalles que faltan, indícanos qué línea es la que da el error, qué error exacto es y en general, danos un [mre] si quieres que te podamos ayudar. Porque en tu IDE te pone las letras, pero dado que nos has puesto un trozo de código al azar, no sabemos qué número es cada línea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. Estás recorriendo posiciones del arreglo que no existen
2. Tienes mal planteado cuándo debe de cambiar tu comparador

**Recuerda** que los arreglos de tamaño `n` tienen posiciones desde `0` hasta `n - 1`. Al poner `n <= x.length` estás comparando de `0` hasta `n`, por lo que salta el error

Tu otro problema es este:

```java
if (x[n] == y[n]) {
    z = true;
}
```

Va a cambiar tu booleano a verdadero siempre que se cumpla esa condición, incluso si antes había detectado que no eran iguales tus arreglos. Lo que te sugeriría hacer es que una vez que halles que la longitud de tu arreglo es diferente o algún elemento no coincide, retornar que *false* (pues ya sabes que no son iguales).

Finalmente tu método debería quedar algo así:

```java
public static boolean comparador(int x[], int y[]) {
    if (x.length != y.length)
        return false;
    
    for (int n = 0; n < x.length; n++) {
        if (x[n] != y[n])
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Recordando que return termina de inmediato el método y devuelve tu valor booleano.

Answer (score -1):

El problema está en el bucle for, ya que se repetirá 4 veces empezando desde 0 y acabando en 3.

Solo cámbialo a:

```
for (int n = 0; n < x.length; n++) {
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).